# 403 (Forbidden) while calling one azure function from another

Tags: azure, azure-functions, http-status-code-403

I need to call an azure function; fn(b), from another azure function; fn(a).

fn(a) -> fn(b)

Both these functions are in same function app. The problem is whenever I try to call (b), I get 403-Forbidden "data at the root level is invalid".

Is it possible to call an azure function from another azure function within same function app?

**Function 1**

```
public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]
            HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("---- C# HTTP trigger function 1 processed a request.");

            UploadToF2(log);
            return null;
        }

        private static IRestResponse UploadToF2(TraceWriter log)
        {
            SomeObject payload = new SomeObject();
            payload.One = "One";
            payload.Two = 2;
            payload.Three = false;
            payload.Four = 4.4;

            var Fn2Url = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["F2Url"]);
            log.Info("Hitting F2 at " + Fn2Url);
            var method = Method.POST;
            var client = new RestClient(Fn2Url);
            var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);

            var request = new RestRequest(method);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            request.AddBody(payload); // uses JsonSerializer

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            return response;
        }
    }

    class SomeObject
    {
        public string One { get; set; }
        public int Two { get; set; }
        public bool Three { get; set; }
        public double Four { get; set; }
    }
```

**Function 2**

```
public static class Function2
    {
        [FunctionName("Function2")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("---- C# HTTP trigger function 2 processed a request.");
            string payload = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            log.Info("payload == "+payload);

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Additional Information:

1. F2Url is a fully qualified url coming from config.
2. I tried running both functions in localhost. It works. I.e. fn(a) can call fn(b) in localhost. However when I host both of them in Azure, fn(b) is not callable from fn(a).
3. I tried a hybrid test too. I.e. I kept one function in local and another one in Azure. It works this way too. I.e. I kept fn(a) in local and fn(b) in Azure, fn(b) is callable.
4. I tried calling fn(b) directly from Postman and again it works.
5. `authLevel` is anonymous for both functions
6. I have IP restrictions (Platform features > Networking > IP restrictions) applied to the Function app. When I remove IP restrictions, Function1 is able to call Function2. However keeping IP restrictions, the call is not allowed.

**The only condition when fn(a) cannot call fn(b) is when both these functions are hosted in Azure.**

Comment: Could you show us some actual code? With the current post it's just a wild guess... For instance: how are you calling the other function?

Comment: Sorry @rickvdbosch, missed to add my code earlier. Have edited original post with the code too.

Comment: And what's the value of `F2Url` in your config? Is it a _complete_ URL? Does the function expect a POST method? Can you call the URL from for instance Postman and see what happens then?

Comment: `F2Url` is a complete url for the fn(b). POST or GET either ways, fn(b) is not callable from fn(a). When I tried calling fn(b) from postman, it works with the exact same request. I also tried calling fn(b) from fn(a) in my localhost and it works too. So I am certainly sure that there is something to do with Azure here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 403 (Forbidden) while calling one azure function from another

If don't add the  **client Ip  in the IP restrictions**, then you test it in you client will get 403 error. Not only call on azure function from another ,but also all functions are restricted if you don't add  the client IP in the IP restrictions.

In your case, you need to add your test [client Ip](https://www.whatismyip.com/) in the IP restrictions, then it will work.

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

Add the test result.

[image]

Comment: I already have my PC's IP in the whitelist for the function. Doesn't work :( . Not able to call Function2 from Function1.

Comment: It is very odd. Based on my test, it works correctly on my side.

Comment: do you have both the functions hosted in Azure?

Comment: Yes, both of functions are hosted on Azure. And  test with you mentioned code.

Comment: You could debug it from the following way, first remove the IP restriction. Then add the following code `string clientIP = ((HttpContextWrapper)req.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.UserHostAddress;` in the azure function to get the client IP. After that add it in the IP restrictions.

Comment: Yes .. thats what the problem was. When I checked the Virtual IP of Function (in Function App > Properties), it showed me different IP. But your trick of getting the IP from the request did the job. THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

Works locally through a GET to Function1 when using:

```
var Fn2Url = "http://localhost:7071/api/Function2";
```

What value are you using in your configuration?

Comment: One caveat here, `authLevel` is ignored when running locally - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#authorization-keys

Comment: @Horia I just added additional information in original question. Can you check it out and revert with your suggestions?

Comment: seems to be working for me, be sure to use the function URL of Function2 that you can get by clicking on **</> Get function URL** in Azure Portal Function App

Comment: @Horia, yes I used the same url.
When you say its working for you, did you try running both the functions in by hosting them in azure?

Comment: Exactly, deployed the two of them in the same Function App, got the URL of the second one from the portal, updated the code, redeployed and tested with a GET on Function1

Comment: Seriously!! Did you try HttpClient or RestClient?

Comment: Your code for the functions. To hit Function1 just a GET via a browser

Comment: GET in browser !!! No .. as i mentioned in my post.. I have already tried hitting individual function via Postman/browser and it works. 

The issue is in hitting Function2 from within Function1

Comment: Oh ya.. sorry @Horia.. read your earlier comment too quickly.
I am adding one more information in the "Additional Information" section.
Basically, I have IP restrictions applied to my function app.
When I remove the IP restrictions, Function1 is able to call Function2.
However when I apply IP restrictions, Function1 is not able to call Function2.
Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Call Function #2 by its full URL, since there's a front end layer that gets hit first before the request makes it to your function app. This is true even for functions calling each other within the same function app.

   ```
   GET https://{func-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/api/function2
   ```
2. If the `authLevel` is not anonymous in `function.json`, pass in the API key as `?code=` —

   ```
   https://{func-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/api/function2?code={API-key}
   ```

   or as a header —

   ```
   GET https://{func-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/api/function2
   x-functions-key: {API-key}
   ```

When running locally (Visual Studio/`func host start`), the value of `authLevel` is ignored. Looking at your decorator, `AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous` is present so most probably that's not it.

More on [authorization keys here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#authorization-keys).

On top of that, you could do better that returning `null` in Function #2: `200 OK`, `202 Accepted`, `204 No Content`, all valid choices depending on what's supposed to happen next (async/sync processing).

Comment: Thanks for your response. 

 1. I am calling Function#2 using fully qualified url which is coming from config.
 2. authLevel for both functions is Anonymous
 3. Returning null could help, however Function#2 is not even getting called. Not even the first line of Function#2 is getting executed (this is why i have log.info as the first line for Function#2).

Comment: Did you try printing out F2 URL to see if it's being read correctly from config?

Comment: yes unfortunately it is correct. Unfortunate coz I am still not able to communicate between the two functions :(

Comment: Did you try HttpClient instead of RestClient?

Comment: No i didnt. Coz RestClient is working in local and I found no particular reason to switch over to HttpClient. But as you suggest, let me try it once.